# Laravel Valet no response after upgrade to 2.0.3

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-valet, caddy

I have used Valet without problems for nearly a year, though occasionally needed a restart or reinstall to get it going. Yesterday I upgraded to a fresh **valet 2.0.3** and as a result and ever since then there is no connection in the browser to any of my `*.dev` hosts (though there is appropriate ping response in the terminal).

Have executed `brew update` and tried a full reinstall several times (with preceding `brew uninstall dnsmasq / php70` etc). There is no error or warning during installation process. Error logs remain empty even after `valet start / restart / park` commands. Also, there are apparently **no caddyfile** and **Caddy** directory generated neither in `~/.valet` nor in `~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel/valet`.
An attempt to download Caddy from github and apply it [like hinted here](https://medium.com/@freekmurze/fixing-laravel-valet-on-macos-sierra-3894053f5a38#.pzryyn9d6) had no effect.

As I need valet badly for my work I have researched night and day for any solution, but not succeeded yet. Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valet 2 utilizes no more Caddy, but **nginx** instead. The solution is to uninstall the present nginx via brew and let nginx get reinstalled during the valet installation procedure. As described here by Switzer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/valet-2-upgrade-all-sites-refuse-to-connect